# Bootstrap 4 Scroll spy not working - no error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am looking for assistance with my bootstrap navbar. The links scroll to the required div but with the fixed nav, it is scrolling too far. I know that I can do it with Bootstrap's scroll spy but it is not working for me. Could somebody tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance

```
<body data-spy="scrollNav" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <nav id="scrollNav" class=" navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-     top navbar-custom navbar-dark">

<a class="navbar-brand suggest-logo" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
    <span class="logo">The </span>Band</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="ml-auto navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tracks">Tracks</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#live">Live</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#insta">Social</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>

    <li>
            <a class="facebook social-pixel"   href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="social-pixel" href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
      <li>
        <a class="social-pixel" href="https://twitter.com/">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
</div>
 </nav>

    ---------------
<div class="container-fluid" id="tracks">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 image">
            <img class="song-image" href="images"> 
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
 <div class="about container-fluid" >
    <div class="row" id="live" data-offset="100">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="https://www.pub.com" target="_blank">Click</a>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

// My JS

`$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#scrollNav' });`

Comment: Peter, try to check your unclosed tags. I can see the nav and a link tag not closed. Some nice scrollspy samples could be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Comment: Thanks @MarcelKohls I forgot the closing a tag but the nav tag wasn't included for some reason. I have read the W3 docs but still having no joy...

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle so that we have a working example?This way it is easy to fork and fix what's wrong.

Comment: Please follow the [Navbar docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/).. your code is not properly structured which makes troublshooting the scrollspy difficult.

Comment: @ZimSystem could you explain why it is not properly structured? I have followed documentation